# Почему не работает привязка события?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
for (var i = 0; i<wrappers.lenght; i++) {
 wrappers[i].onclick = function() {
   this.firstChild.style.display = 'none';
  };
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">asdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">asdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">asdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">asdasd</div>
</div>
```

Почему данный код не срабатывает, по клику на блок должен пропадать текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте `firstElementChild`, он берёт именно первый дочерний элемент, а не любой дочерний node.

Кроме того вы `length` неправильно написали, последние буквы перепутаны.

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
for (var i = 0; i<wrappers.length; i++) {
 wrappers[i].onclick = function() {
   this.firstElementChild.style.display = 'none';

  };
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">asdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">asdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">asdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">asdasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не помогло) Ошибок в консоли так же нет

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi ошибка в length, я добавил в ответ

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi  если ответ решил вашу задачу, можете его отметить как ответ